# Short story about "leaping" (matter transfer without "beaming")

Tags: story-identification

This was a story, perhaps a novella,  1960s era, that began by explaining "leaping"--the ability to transfer from place to place, but without any external device. The origin story was that a scientist accidentally created some explosive force and leaped to safety before he was in danger.  The story continued to explain all sorts of advances and the institutionalization of "leaping" (leaping stations, etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The discovery of your "leaping" is very, very similar to the discovery of *Jaunting* in Alfred Bester's book [**The Stars My Destination.**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Stars_My_Destination)

Comment: That's the one, thanks! My "leaping" neuron apparently had a fight with my "jaunting" neuron and beat the stuffing out of it.  Forgot completely that the scientist's name was Jaunte.